# bug with nexus 5 calendar

Tags: calendar, nexus-5, google-calendar

For some reason the calendar in nexus 5 lg acts strange.. it keeps on taking me back to 1970.. and the date selector keeps on changing at a hysterical speed. any idea how to address this?

Comment: You mean to say the calendar opens in the year 1970 by default? Is the date and month correct? When you say date selector, which control are you talking about? Can you post a screenshot? Is your date and time shown in the phone settings correct?

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt seem normal. If your date/time-settings in the Android System-Settings-Menu are correct (maybe change it by hand to the current day & year to test it) there should be no issues like this.

If after this there is still this issue please go into your App-settings (Settings > Apps) and search for google calendar. Here please delete data and cache and maybe also installed updates. Then make a device-restart and re-download the update and check again. This should solve issues if they are caused by the problem-app itself.

In case you have other Calendar apps installed, or other apps that interact with systems time-settings you should try to disable (Settings > Apps > AppThatHasProblem > Disable) it to test if this was the error.

If all that doesnt help (also not the data & cache-cleaning etc) and you absolutley want to use this calendar (maybe try Sunrise, its really very good) i can only suggest a factory-reset, sorry.